# How to get transformed coordinate in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I draw a solid sphere like the followings:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(0.015, 0.015, 0.015);
    glRotatef(90, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(0.0, 200, 0.0);
    glRotatef(-20, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glRotatef(-20, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(78.75, -110.74, -13.53);
    glutSolidSphere(4.0f,15,15);
glPopMatrix();
```

How can I get the transformed coordinates of this solid sphere?

Comment: Are you a newbie OpenGL programmer?

Comment: You are using the original "Red Book" era OpenGL programming model that has been superseded by a better technique.  Because of this the majority of tutorials you find on the internet will be showing you how to do things in a way that has been deprecated for a long time. I recommend that you get "OpenGL Shading Language (3rd Edition, 2009)" http://tinyurl.com/c5fpaw6 It not only gives a primer on the approach that programmers use (with shaders), it also has a history showing how things used to be done with a "fixed function" pipeline and how the equivalent functions are now done with shaders.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the state variables `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX` by the function `glget`.

It returns the current matrix from `ModelView` stack. I think that is what you need.

Comment: Well in part. He wants the transformed coordinate, so after getting the matrix he then has to do the transformation of the sphere's coordinates with it.

Comment: Christian, you are correct. Could you please let me know how to get it?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think this would be useful to a beginner OpenGL programmer.

Answer (score -1):

Put the translated coordinates in variables, then you won't have to retrieve the transformed coordinates of the shape.

```
float solidSphereX = whatever;
float solidSphereY = whatever;
float solidSphereZ = whatever;
float solidSphereRotationX = whatever in radians;
float solidSphereRotationY = whatever in radians;
float solidSphereRotationZ = whatever in radians;
...
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(solidSphereRotationX, solidSphereRotationY, solidSphereRotationZ);
glTranslatef(solidSphereX, solidSphereY, solidSphereZ);
glPopMatrix();
```